# Drag and drop images from left to right side Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, drag-and-drop

I am working on Flutter application and I want to the functionality of toolbox. Drag and drop the elements from left panel to right panel. Currently I can drag drop element from left to right but the issue is once the element is dropped anywhere in the right panel I cannot drag drop it further in the same panel i.e. right. I want to change the location of dropped element but cannot do so. It remain there where is dropped it.

This is me code.

```html
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: DrawerWidget(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: Text(
          'Table Layout',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title.merge(
                TextStyle(letterSpacing: 1.3),
              ),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.blue[100],
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.30,
              child: ListView.separated(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                itemCount: 3,
                separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return const SizedBox(
                    height: 12.0,
                  );
                },
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return MenuListItem(
                    photoProvider: images[index],
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.blue[200],
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 6.0,
                  ),
                  child: Container(
                    height: double.infinity,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    child: DragTarget(
                      builder: (context, candidateItems, rejectedItems) {
                        return Container();
                      },
                      onAccept: (item) {
                        return Container(
                          height: 100,
                          width: 100,
                          color: Colors.pink,
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                 
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```html
class MenuListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  MenuListItem({
    Key key,
    @required this.photoProvider,
    this.isDepressed = false,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String photoProvider;
  final bool isDepressed;

  final GlobalKey _draggableKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Draggable(
      dragAnchor: DragAnchor.pointer,
      feedback: DraggingListItem(
        dragKey: _draggableKey,
        photoProvider: photoProvider,
      ),
      child: Material(
        elevation: 12.0,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 120,
              height: 120,
              child: Center(
                child: AnimatedContainer(
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                  curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                  height: isDepressed ? 115 : 120,
                  width: isDepressed ? 115 : 120,
                  child: Image.asset(
                    photoProvider,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me how to achieve drag drop like I want. Thanks